# wrong item is being selected in listview when selecting checkbox

Tags: android, listview

**
When i select the items which are at the bottom of the listview,they wont get selected,
rather only first four items in the list is being selected.its because the items are out of view.
what to do to get these items in view ??sometimes the item gets randomly selected.
Please help me.
thank you
Here is my code**

```
 Main activity

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ExceptionAppActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

    private final int REQUEST_CODE = 20;
    String flagg;
    String empNm = Constants.Common.STR_BLNK;
    String empCode = Constants.Common.STR_BLNK;

    SessionManager session = null;
    final Context context = this;
    static Typeface custom_font = null;
    TextView lblExcId, lblExcEmpNm, lblExcFrmDt, lblExcFrmDtVal, lblExcToDtVal, lblExcTyp, lblExcStat, lblExcEmpCmt;
    Button btnExcRej, btnExcApp, btnExcSrch, btnExcExit;
    CheckBox cb, chkBox;
    ListView excSrchListView;
    ArrayList<Excp> Results;
    CustomListViewAdapter cla;
    ExceptionAppDao eCon = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.exception_app_activity);

        /* get Resources from Xml file */
        btnExcApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExcApp);
        btnExcRej = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExcRej);
        btnExcSrch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExcSrch);
        btnExcExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExcExit);
        lblExcEmpNm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblExcEmpNm);
        lblExcFrmDt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblExcFrmDt);
        lblExcFrmDtVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblExcFrmDtVal);
        lblExcToDtVal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblExcToDtVal);
        lblExcTyp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblExcTyp);
        lblExcStat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblExcStat);
        lblExcEmpCmt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblExcEmpCmt);
        lblExcId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblExcId);
        chkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkBx);
        excSrchListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.excSrchListView);

        // Session Manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf");

        // Connection object for Login
        eCon = new ExceptionAppDao(context);
        // get User Details from Session
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashMap = session.getUserDetails();
        empNm = hashMap.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMP_NM);
        empCode = hashMap.get(SessionManager.KEY_EMP_CODE);

        btnExcApp.setTypeface(custom_font);
        btnExcRej.setTypeface(custom_font);
        btnExcSrch.setTypeface(custom_font);
        btnExcExit.setTypeface(custom_font);
        new SyncData(empCode).execute();

        if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
        }
        // on click any button
        addButtonListener();
    }

    /**
     * on click any button
     */
    private void addButtonListener() {
        btnExcApp.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnExcRej.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnExcSrch.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnExcExit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<Excp>> {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

        List<ExcpMstVo> rtnExcVo = new ArrayList<ExcpMstVo>();
        ExcpMstVo rtnExcMstVo = new ExcpMstVo();
        ArrayList<Excp> resultLst = new ArrayList<Excp>();
        ExceptionService_Service excpServObj = new ExceptionService_Service();
        String syncFlg = Constants.Common.STR_BLNK;
        private View rootView;
        String flag = "";
        int x;
        boolean success = false;
        boolean successSyncFlag = false;
        int countApp = 0;

        public SyncData(String str) {
            syncFlg = str;
        }

        public SyncData(View rootView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.rootView = rootView;
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Excp> doInBackground(String... params) {
            ExceptionSearchCriteria vo = new ExceptionSearchCriteria();
            ExcpMstVo excpMstVo = new ExcpMstVo();

            try {
                if (syncFlg.equals(empCode)) {
                    vo = setAppData(vo);
                    rtnExcVo = excpServObj.getExceptionPort().searchExceptionApproval(vo);
                    if (!(rtnExcVo.isEmpty())) {
                        System.out.println("rtnExcVo" + rtnExcVo.size());
                        Excp exc = null;
                        for (ExcpMstVo excMstVo : rtnExcVo) {
                            exc = new Excp();
                            exc.setExcId(excMstVo.getExcpId());
                            exc.setEmpCode(excMstVo.getEmpCode());
                            exc.setEmpNm(excMstVo.getEmpnm());
                            exc.setFromDt(excMstVo.getFromDt());
                            exc.setToDt(excMstVo.getToDt());
                            exc.setExcType(excMstVo.getExcpType());
                            exc.setExcStatus(excMstVo.getStatus());
                            exc.setEmpComments(excMstVo.getEmpComments());
                            exc.setExcFor(excMstVo.getExcpFor());
                            exc.setExcReason(excMstVo.getExcpReason());

                            resultLst.add(exc);
                            Results = resultLst;
                            success = true;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (btnExcApp.equals(rootView.getRootView().findViewById(rootView.getId()))) {
                    for (x = excSrchListView.getChildCount() - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                        cb = (CheckBox) excSrchListView.getChildAt(x).findViewById(R.id.chkBx);
                        if (cb.isChecked()) {

                            excpMstVo = setEmpData();
                            rtnExcMstVo = excpServObj.getExceptionPort().changeExceptionStatus(excpMstVo);

                            System.out.println("rtnExcMstVo:::::" + rtnExcMstVo.getExcpId());
                            System.out.println("rtnExcMstVoStatuss:::::" + rtnExcMstVo.getStatus());
                            countApp++;
                            success = false;
                        }
                    }
                    /*if (countApp == 0) {

                    } else*/ if (countApp > 0) {
                        new SyncData(rootView).execute();
                        //flagg = false;

                    }
                    System.out.println("rtnExcMstVo:::::" + rtnExcMstVo.getExcpId());
                    System.out.println("rtnExcMstVoStatuss:::::" + rtnExcMstVo.getStatus());
                }
                // get dump from device
                CopyDbFromDevice cd = new CopyDbFromDevice();
                cd.copyDbToSdcard(context);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("success::::" + success);
            successSyncFlag = success;
            System.out.println("successSyncFlag::::::::" + successSyncFlag);
            return resultLst;
        }

        private ExcpMstVo setEmpData() {
            ExcpMstVo excpMstVo = new ExcpMstVo();

            excpMstVo.setExcpId(Results.get(x).getExcId());
            excpMstVo.setFromDt(Results.get(x).getFromDt());
            excpMstVo.setStatus(Constants.Status.STAT_APPRV);
            excpMstVo.setMngrComments("");
            excpMstVo.setApprovedBy(empCode);
            excpMstVo.setLoggedInUser(empCode);

            return excpMstVo;
        }

        private ExceptionSearchCriteria setAppData(ExceptionSearchCriteria vo) {
            vo.setApprover(empCode);
            vo.setStatus(Constants.Status.PENDING_APPROVAL);
            return vo;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Excp> searchResults) {
            System.out.println("successSyncFlag1::::::::" + successSyncFlag);
            if (successSyncFlag == true) {
                System.out.println("entering ON POST IF");
                cla = new CustomListViewAdapter(ExceptionAppActivity.this, resultLst);
                excSrchListView.setAdapter(cla);
            } 
            else {
                System.out.println("ENTERING ONPOST ELSE PART ");
                System.out.println("successSyncFlag2:;;;;;; " + successSyncFlag);
                System.out.println("success2:::::::::::: " + success);
                System.out.println("NEW METHOD STARTED:::::;");
                if (countApp == 0) {
                    System.out.println("ENTERING COUNT APP 0 ");
                    String flag = "checkItemApp";
                    dialogBox(flag);
                } else {
                    new SyncData(empCode).execute();
                    String flag = "excApp";
                    dialogBox(flag);
                    System.out.println("NEW METHOD STARTED1:::::::::");
                }
            }
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int countRej = 0;
        int id = v.getId();
        Intent intent = null;
        if (id == R.id.btnExcApp) {
            new SyncData(v).execute();

        } else if (id == R.id.btnExcRej) {
            int itemPos = 0;
            for (int y = excSrchListView.getChildCount() - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
                cb = (CheckBox) excSrchListView.getChildAt(y).findViewById(R.id.chkBx);
                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemPos = y;
                    cla.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    countRej++;
                }
            }
            // Check if any Exception is selected for Rejection and proceed
            // accordingly
            if (countRej == 1) {
                CustomListViewAdapter cla = (CustomListViewAdapter) excSrchListView.getAdapter();
                Object o = cla.getItem(itemPos);
                Excp selectedExcp = (Excp) o;
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ExcAppDtlsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("selectedExcp", selectedExcp);
                intent.putExtra("readOnly", false);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

            } else if (countRej == 0) {
                // show dialogue of Select at least 1
                String flag = "checkItemRej";
                dialogBox(flag);

            } else if (countRej > 1) {
                String flag = "checkOnlyOne";
                dialogBox(flag);
                for (int y = excSrchListView.getChildCount() - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
                    cb = (CheckBox) excSrchListView.getChildAt(y).findViewById(R.id.chkBx);
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        itemPos = y;
                        cb.setChecked(false);
                        cla.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.btnExcSrch) {
            intent = new Intent(this, FurtherSearchActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("readOnly", false);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.btnExcExit) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * create alert dialog
     * 
     * @param flag
     */
    private void dialogBox(String flag) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        /*if (flag == "excApp") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exception Approved successfully !");
        } else*/ if (flag == "checkOnlyOne") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Please select only one item to reject !");
        } else if (flag == "checkItemRej") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select Exception to Reject !");
        }
        /*else if (flag == "checkItemApp") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select Exception to Approve !");
        } */
        else if (flag == "excRej") {
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Exception Rejected successfully !");
        } 
        /*else {
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Flag - " + flag);
        }*/

        Dialogbox dbx = new Dialogbox(context);
        dbx.createDialogAlert(flag, alertDialogBuilder);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void

    onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // REQUEST_CODE is defined above
        /*
         * if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) { //
         * Extract name value from result extras flagg =
         * data.getExtras().getString("flagg"); if ((flagg.equals("Approve")) ||
         * (flagg.equals("Reject"))) { for (int x = 0; x <
         * excSrchListView.getChildCount(); x++) { cb = (CheckBox)
         * excSrchListView.getChildAt(x).findViewById( R.id.chkBx); if
         * (cb.isChecked()) { // If Approval is successful remove from list
         * Results.remove(x); cb.setChecked(false); cla.notifyDataSetChanged();
         * if (flagg.equals("Approve")) { dialogBox("excApp"); } else {
         * dialogBox("excRej"); } } }
         * 
         * } }
         */

    }
}
```

CUSTOM LIST ADAPTER

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eanda.smarttime_mobi.R;
import com.eanda.smarttime_mobi.model.Excp;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<Excp> searchArrayList;
    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> checked;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Typeface custom_font = null;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Excp> results) {

        searchArrayList = results;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        checked = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>(getCount());
        custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf");
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return searchArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // created custom view
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.myTable = (TableLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myTable);

            holder.txtExcId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblExcId);
            holder.txtEmpNm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblExcEmpNm);
            holder.txtFrmDt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblExcFrmDtVal);
            holder.txtToDt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblExcToDtVal);
            holder.txtExcTyp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblExcTyp);
            holder.txtExcStat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblExcStat);
            holder.txtEmpCmt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblExcEmpCmt);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBx);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.chkBx, holder.checkBox);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        System.out.println("exception_name" + searchArrayList.get(position).getEmpNm());

        holder.txtExcId.setText(Integer.toString(searchArrayList.get(position).getExcId()));
        holder.txtEmpNm.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getEmpNm());
        holder.txtFrmDt.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getFromDt());
        holder.txtToDt.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getToDt());
        holder.txtExcTyp.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getExcType());
        holder.txtExcStat.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getExcStatus());
        holder.txtEmpCmt.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getEmpComments());

        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(searchArrayList.get(position).isChecked());
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBx);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                System.out.println("selected");

                int checkBoxId = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(buttonView.isChecked() ? true : false);
                searchArrayList.get(checkBoxId).setChecked(buttonView.isChecked() ? true : false);
                System.out.println("checkBoxId " + checkBoxId);
            }
        });

        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);

        holder.txtExcId.setTypeface(custom_font);
        holder.txtEmpNm.setTypeface(custom_font);
        holder.txtFrmDt.setTypeface(custom_font);
        holder.txtToDt.setTypeface(custom_font);
        holder.txtExcTyp.setTypeface(custom_font);
        holder.txtExcStat.setTypeface(custom_font);
        holder.txtEmpCmt.setTypeface(custom_font);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TableLayout myTable;
        TextView txtExcId;
        TextView txtEmpNm;
        TextView txtFrmDt;
        TextView txtToDt;
        TextView txtExcTyp;
        TextView txtExcStat;
        TextView txtEmpCmt;
        CheckBox checkBox;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBx);`

  You already have check box reference stored in the holder, I wonder why you are initializing it again.
- `holder.checkBox.setChecked(buttonView.isChecked() ? true : false);`

  Checked state will be changed when the user clicks the checkbox, so no need to change the checked state again.

Try the following code

```
----
----
holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
holder.checkBox.setChecked(searchArrayList.get(position).isChecked());
holder.checkBox..setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                System.out.println("selected");

                int checkBoxId = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();

                searchArrayList.get(checkBoxId).setChecked(buttonView.isChecked() ? true : false);
                System.out.println("checkBoxId " + checkBoxId);
            }
        });
holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
-----
----
```

Comment: the problem is when i select 5 th item ,i shud be able to see that item data.but all i can  see is  1 st item data.simillarly when i select 6 th item ,2nd item data is displayed...how to get these item in view?